AndroidX - IconPicker preference (or custom list preference)
For years I have been using a nice IconPickerPreference like the one in this code.
The old android.preference library is deprecated. Since about 4 years Android provides the new androidx.preference library.
Performing a search and replace the old android.preference with androidx.preference is not a working solution for the example icon picker preference.
Do you have an implementation of the IconPickerPreference? Each row consists of a name and an icon.
I was not able to find a good solution on the internet for quite some time. I hope you can help. A similar question does not provide for a good answer.
The solutions I found for android.preference that were closest to what I need are below. The problem is that the @Override onPrepareDialogBuilder is not in the androidx.preference.ListPreference class.

I dont understand, what is stopping you from changing to androidx.preferences from the old preferences?

Why not git fork, search and replace in files, and then git push? I'd also say just use androidx.preference.PreferenceManager and androidx.preference.Preference. Alternatively, just enable the Jetifier to change the class mappings.

The design of the classes changed since androidx.preference. For example, the "@Override protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)" is not in the androidx.preference.ListPreference.

After a lot of experimenting, I came up to this solution. First step is to create a solution for customizing the preference. Below you find a custom list preference.
A custom list preference for AndroidX.preference:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.preference.ListPreference;


public class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {
    CustomListPreferenceAdapter customListPreferenceAdapter = null;
    Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    CharSequence[] entries;
    CharSequence[] entryValues;
    ArrayList<RadioButton> rButtonList;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private String mValue;
    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        rButtonList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onClick() {
        entries = getEntries();
        entryValues = getEntryValues();
        mValue = getValue();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        customListPreferenceAdapter = new CustomListPreferenceAdapter(R.layout.custom_list_preference_row);
        builder.setAdapter(customListPreferenceAdapter, null);
        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.show();

    }

    private class CustomListPreferenceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int layoutIndex = 0;
        public CustomListPreferenceAdapter( int layoutIndex) {
            this.layoutIndex = layoutIndex;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return entries.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            CustomHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null) {
                row = mInflater.inflate(this.layoutIndex, parent, false);
                holder = new CustomHolder(row, position);
                row.setTag(holder);
                row.setClickable(true);
            }
            return row;
        }

        class CustomHolder {
            private TextView text = null;
            private RadioButton rButton = null;

            CustomHolder(View row, int position) {
                text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view_row_text_view);
                text.setText(entries[position]);
                rButton = (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view_row_radio_button);
                rButton.setId(position);
            }
        }
    }
}

In the PreferenceScreen I get the result of the selection.
Or a custom icon picker preference. A rough version is below. I stimulate you to improve the version.
public class IconPickerPreference extends ListPreference {
    CustomListPreferenceAdapter customListPreferenceAdapter = null;
    Context mContext;
    View mView;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Resources resources;
    private String selectedIconFile, defaultIconFile;
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    CharSequence[] entries;
    CharSequence[] entryValues;
    ArrayList<RadioButton> rButtonList;
    private List<IconItem> icons;

    private String mValue;
    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    public IconPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        resources = context.getResources();
        rButtonList = new ArrayList<>();

        entries = getEntries();
        entryValues = getEntryValues();
        mValue = getValue();
        icons = new ArrayList<IconItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            IconItem item = new IconItem(entries[i], entryValues[i], ( i == currentIndex));
            icons.add(item);
        }

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes( attrs, R.styleable.attrs_icon, 0, 0);
        try {
            defaultIconFile = a.getString(R.styleable.attrs_icon_iconFile);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        setWidgetLayoutResource( R.layout.prefernce_list_with_icons);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick() {
        entries = getEntries();
        entryValues = getEntryValues();
        mValue = getValue();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        customListPreferenceAdapter = new CustomListPreferenceAdapter(R.layout.prefernce_row_with_icon, icons);
        builder.setAdapter(customListPreferenceAdapter, null);
        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        mView = holder.itemView;
        mValue = getValue();
        IconItem selectedIcon = getIconByIndexValue( mValue, icons);
        TextView tvItitle = mView.findViewById( R.id.title);
        tvItitle.setText( getTitle());
        ImageView iconImage = mView.findViewById( R.id.iconSelected);
        if( iconImage != null) {
            int identifier = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier( selectedIcon.file, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
            iconImage.setBackgroundResource(identifier);
            iconImage.setTag(selectedIconFile);
        }
    }

    private IconItem getIconByIndexValue( String value, List<IconItem> icons) {
        IconItem defaultIcon = icons.get( 0);
        int index = Integer.parseInt( value);
        if( index < 0 || index >= icons.size()) {
            return defaultIcon;
        }
        return icons.get( index);
    }

    void updatePreferenceIcon( int position) {
        setValue( "" + position);
    }

    private class CustomListPreferenceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int layoutIndex = 0;
        List<IconItem> icons;

        public CustomListPreferenceAdapter( int layoutIndex, List<IconItem> icons) {
            this.layoutIndex = layoutIndex;
            this.icons = icons;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return entries.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            CustomHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null) {
                row = mInflater.inflate(this.layoutIndex, parent, false);
                holder = new CustomHolder(row, position);
                row.setTag(holder);
                row.setClickable(true);
                row.setOnClickListener( v -> {
                    updatePreferenceIcon( position);
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                });
            }
            return row;
        }

        class CustomHolder {
            private TextView text = null;
            private ImageView icon = null;

            CustomHolder(View row, int position) {
                text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.pref_icon_title);
                text.setText(entries[position]);
                icon = row.findViewById(R.id.pref_icon_icon);
                mValue = getValue();
                int identifier = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier( icons.get( position).file, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                icon.setBackgroundResource(identifier);
                icon.setTag(selectedIconFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private class IconItem {
        private String  file;
        private boolean isChecked;
        private String  name;

        public IconItem(CharSequence name, CharSequence file, boolean isChecked) {
            this(name.toString(), file.toString(), isChecked);
        }

        public IconItem(String name, String file, boolean isChecked) {
            this.name = name;
            this.file = file;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }
}

